# Data Loading Data into Sencha ComboBox with Ajax

Tags: c#, .net, extjs

I am learning extension.js, curently trying to loading remote data trough an Ajax call into a sencha combobox. I see the data comming as JSON but it is not loaded into combobox.

I am trying like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">        

    // Attach to onDOMReady event
    Ext.onReady(onReady);

    function onReady() {

        // Create store

        var states = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: 'AspDropDownControl.aspx/GetCountries', // ASP.NET WebService call in GET format
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json' // IMPORTANT! Without this FireFox will not understand WebService response 
                }
            }),
            root: 'd', // Root Json element, always 'd'
            id: 'CountryId', // Identifier column, ExtJS needs it to recognize rows
            fields: ['CountryId', 'CountryName'] // Simple definition of columns
        });

        var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            xtype: 'combo',
            fieldLabel: "Selecy your Country",
            mode: "remote",
            valueField: "CountryId",
            displayField: "CountryName",
            minChars: 1,
            //allowBlank: false, //to make it required
            anchor: "100%",
            emptyText: "Select an Country...",
            store: states,
            lazyRender: true,
            renderTo: Ext.get('content')
        });
    }
</script>
```

I am able to see JSON response as

```
{"d":[
{"CountryId":1,"CountryName":"Algeria"},
{"CountryId":2,"CountryName":"Benin"},
{"CountryId":3,"CountryName":"Cameroon"},
{"CountryId":4,"CountryName":"Chad"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors:

**First**: You should define a model to avoid problems with the automodels. This may not be your problem but it can be considered as best-practice. [See the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)

```
Ext.define('CountryModel',{
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   id: 'CountryId',
   fields: [{name:'CountryId',type:'int'}, 'CountryName'] 
});
```

Assign this model to the store with the following config line: `model:'CountryModel'`

**Second**: `Ext.data.JsonStore` is a shorthand for a `Ext.data.Store` pre-configured with a proxy for reading JSON from ajax request. But you are setting your own proxy and will therefore override this setting. In short: if you set your own proxy there is no benefit when using `Ext.data.JsonStore`

**Third**: Defining

```
root: 'd', 
id: 'CountryId', 
fields: ['CountryId', 'CountryName']
```

on store level will have no effect cause the store didn't have any of these config properties. They belong to the reader/model. But there is a benefit of using models; the store will copy some settings of the model to proxy / reader for you.

Try this Store:

```
// don't forget to insert the model definition before you call this
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'CountryModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'AspDropDownControl.aspx/GetCountries',
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'd'
        }
    }
});
```

This is totally untested and you may still run into some issues but it should show you how it has to be done.

> Please note that the headers are just applied to any request. They
>   have nothing to do with reading and may only help the Server to better
>   understand the incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working with a JsonStore myself, but as far as I know "Id" and "root" are part of the [Ext.data.reader.Reader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader)

(I assume you want the idProperty btw, not the id, because they are completely different)

Your reader should look something like this

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'd',
    idProperty: 'CountryId'
}
```

Hope this helps and I am not completely misunderstanding something

Comment: i have tried commenting these two also, but they have no efects.